# Nodejs, Express & WebSockets: Relaying a message to all clients other than the sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I've got a node/express/ws server up and running with the following code

```js
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs= require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var WebSocket = require('ws');

var server = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/wss/new/certificate.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/wss/new/private.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/wss/new/ca_bundle.pem'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var web = express();

//Server initializations
var httpServer = http.createServer(web);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(server, web);
var wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server: httpsServer });
httpServer.listen(8080);
httpsServer.listen(58443, function listen(connection) {});
```

and I have the following to listen for events sent from clients

```js
wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            client.send(data);
        }
    });
};

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        if(JSON.parse(data)) {
            data = JSON.parse(data+'\n');
            if(data.proto == "SN_NOTI") { //Want to send to everyone that's not the sender.
                var mes = {
                    type: 'NOTI',
                    title: data.title,
                    body: data.body
                }
                wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify(mes));
            } else if (data.proto == "UP_NOTI") { //Send to everyone, including sender
                var msg = {type: "UP_NOTI"}
                wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify(msg));
            } else if (data.proto == "msg") {
                console.log(data.value);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Had some trouble.");
        }
    });
});
```

What I want to do is to send a message `var = mes { type: "NOTI", ... }` to all other clients other than the sender (as the sender doesn't need a browser notification).

Comment: look into `socket.braodcast`

Comment: There is a typo, `socket.broadcast` it is :p

Comment: I've tried playing with socket.io although I'm not a fan therefore have left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.broadcast` method sends message to all, Hence you need to use the `.on(connection)` method like this,

Here the `client !== ws` condition excludes the sender.

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!